# SQL Query - SUM and JOIN multiple tables but return missing record

Tags: sql-server

SQL Query - SUM and JOIN multiple tables but return missing record;

Good day!

here's the table lists;

- Barcodes Table
- Item Ledger Entry Table
- Trans_ Sales Entry Table
- Transfer Line Table

Note: all table has a relation Store No/Location, Item No and Variant Code

Need help.

when i JOIN and SUM the ***Trans_ Sales Entry Table*** and ***Transfer Line Table*** , but the query result return some missing record

[screenshot: missing record.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAAH1.jpg)

Thank you!

**here's my sql query code;**

```
    ;WITH Barcodes AS
(
SELECT
    [BBI$Barcodes].[Item No_]
    ,[BBI$Barcodes].[Description]
    ,[BBI$Barcodes].[Variant Code]
FROM [BBI$Barcodes]
),
ILEtransfer AS
(
SELECT
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
    ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [PDel]

FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
WHERE
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
    AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '4'
GROUP BY
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
),
ILEmsales AS
(
SELECT
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
    ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [MSales]

FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
WHERE
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
    AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '1'
    AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Document No_] NOT LIKE 'HP%'
GROUP BY
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
),
ILEpadj AS
(
SELECT
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
    ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [PAdj]

FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
WHERE
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
    AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '2'
GROUP BY
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
),
ILEnadj AS
(
SELECT
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
    ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [NAdj]

FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
WHERE
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
    AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '3'
GROUP BY
    [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
    ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
),
Transfeline  AS
(
SELECT
       [BBI$Transfer Line].[Transfer-to Code]   
      ,[BBI$Transfer Line].[Item No_]
      ,MAX([BBI$Transfer Line].[Description]) AS [Description]
      ,MAX([BBI$Transfer Line].[Description 2]) AS [Description 2]
      ,[BBI$Transfer Line].[Variant Code]
      ,SUM([BBI$Transfer Line].[Quantity]) AS [UDel]
  FROM [BBI$Transfer Line]
  WHERE
  [BBI$Transfer Line].[Transfer-to Code] = 'HPGW'
  GROUP BY
       [BBI$Transfer Line].[Transfer-to Code]   
      ,[BBI$Transfer Line].[Item No_]
      ,[BBI$Transfer Line].[Variant Code]
),
TSEpsales AS
(
SELECT
    [BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Store No_]
    ,[BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_]
    ,[BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Variant Code]
    ,SUM([BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Quantity]) AS [PSales]
FROM [BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry]
WHERE
    [BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Store No_]='HPGW'
    AND [BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Transaction No_] NOT IN (5271,5272,5273,5278,5279,5280,5281,5282,5283,5284,5285,5286,8530,8531,8532,8533,8534,8535,8536,8537,13133,13849) 
GROUP BY
    [BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Store No_]
    ,[BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_]
    ,[BBI$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Variant Code]
)

SELECT DISTINCT
        BAR.[Item No_] AS [Item No_]
        ,BAR.[Description] AS [Description]
        ,BAR.[Variant Code] AS [Variant Code]
        ,ISNULL(ILETR.[PDel],0) AS [PDel]
        ,ISNULL(ILEMS.[MSales],0) AS [MSales]
        ,ISNULL(ILEPA.[PAdj],0) AS [PAdj]
        ,ISNULL(ILENA.[NAdj],0) AS [NAdj]
        ,ISNULL(TL.[UDel],0) AS [UDel]
        ,ISNULL(TSEPS.[PSales],0) AS [PSales]
        ,ISNULL(ILETR.[PDel],0)+ISNULL(ILEPA.[PAdj],0)+ISNULL(TL.[UDel],0)+ISNULL(ILEMS.[MSales],0)+ISNULL(ILENA.[NAdj],0)+ISNULL(TSEPS.[PSales],0) AS Total

FROM [BBI$Barcodes] BAR

LEFT JOIN [ILEtransfer] ILETR
ON ILETR.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
AND ILETR.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]

LEFT JOIN [ILEmsales] ILEMS
ON ILEMS.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
AND ILEMS.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]

LEFT JOIN [ILEpadj] ILEPA
ON ILEPA.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
AND ILEPA.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]

LEFT JOIN [ILEnadj] ILENA
ON ILENA.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
AND ILENA.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]

FULL JOIN [Transfeline] TL
ON TL.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
AND TL.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]

FULL JOIN [TSEpsales] TSEPS
ON TSEPS.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
AND TSEPS.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]

WHERE
ILETR.[Location]='HPGW'
AND ILETR.[Entry Type]='4'
OR ILEMS.[Entry Type]='1'
OR ILEPA.[Entry Type]='2'
OR ILENA.[Entry Type]='3'
```

Comment: Please don;t tag multiple RDBMS, it only causes confusion. Seeing as you are using brackets (`[]`) as a delimit identifier it appears you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Also, don't link to random files on Dropbox; if something is relevant to your question include it in the actual question. Users are *very* unlikely to trust a file from a complete stranger on the internet (many of us are IT professionals and know the dangers of downloading an unknown file from an unknown source). Sample data is best presented as DDL and DML statements, or otherwise as (well formatted) tabular formatted `text`.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry, i will edit my post, again im sorry

Comment: Please show us the query of your result `screenshot: missing record.jpg` and the query result for `Transfer Line Table` wiout using JOIN.

Comment: @etsuhisa, thank you for reply, is it okay if put it my google sheet and share it with you to view the query results, thank you again